unexpected behavior with odometry/filtered from robot_localization
I'm using two IMU sensors witmotion wt901C (LINK LINK) and wheel encoder to calculate odometry. I installed the robot_localization package to merge the data and generate an odometry/filtered. However, according to the video (LINK_VIDEO), I notice two situations:

the odometry/filtered never starts exactly at the same position as the odometry calculated with the wheel encoders. It always seems to start 1 or 2 centimeters ahead of the odometry coming from the wheel encoders. Is there a way to make the odometry/filtered start at the same position as the odometry from the wheel encoders?

the odometry/filtered is in constant motion, slowly sliding backwards even if the robot's wheels are stopped. Is there a way to prevent this small movement when the robot's wheels are stopped?


I don't have much experience with robot_localization and any tips are appreciated.
my robot_localization yaml file is this:
frequency: 50

two_d_mode: true
publish_tf: true  


#Frame IDs
#map_frame: map                        
odom_frame: odom                       
base_link_frame: base_footprint        
world_frame: odom                      


odom0: /odom
odom0_config: [false, false, false, false, false, true,
               true, true, false, false, false, true,
               false, false, false]
odom0_differential: false
odom0_relative: false
odom0_queue_size: 10


imu0: /imu1
imu0_config: [false, false, false, false, false, true,
              false, false, false, false, false, true,
              true, false, false]
imu0_differential: true
imu0_relative: false
imu0_queue_size: 10

imu1: /imu2
imu1_config: [false, false, false, false, false, true,
              false, false, false, false, false, true,
              true, false, false]
imu1_differential: true
imu1_relative: false
imu0_queue_size: 10

The topics /odom, /imu1 and /imu2 are publishing data at a frequency of 50Hz

I'd usually ask for sample messages from every sensor input, but in this case, I think the answer to both issues is very likely that you are attempting to fuse X acceleration from your IMUs. Try turning that off (set it to false for both IMUs) and see if it helps. If it does, you can do a few things:

Leave it that way
Decrease the covariance for your wheel encoder linear X velocity
Increase the process noise covariance for linear X velocity

